# Cant set Ctrl + Shift + E as chrome extension command

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to register `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `E` as command for my chrome extension, it should work according to my understanding from the rules listed [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/commands/) but it isn't working.

I noticed even the command in the example `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Y` doesn't work.
They don't perform the necessary action.

I understand these commands are just suggestions but I'm not sure why these combinations aren't working.
When logging with `chrome.commands.getAll()` the shortcut is replaced by empty string.

Here is my manifest V3 file:

```
...

"commands": {
    "commandName": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "default": "Ctrl+Shift+E",
          "mac": "Command+Shift+E"
        },
        "description": "description"
      }
}
...
```

Other combinations work for example `Ctrl + U` or `Ctrl + Shift + U`

Comment: Something else is intercepting this hotkey e.g. another extension.

Comment: How can I track down it? It isn't listed here chrome://extensions/shortcuts

Comment: It may be another application in the OS.